# c:\windows\regedit.exe copy fails

Tags: security, windows-7, regedit

Tonight I have come across a strange phenomenon on win7 (64bit pro).
When I copy regedit.exe to for example c:\ I am no longer able to run it. It simply doesn't start any more.
When I try to debug it whit olly db, olly says it's no valid 32bit pe file any more. A closer look reveals that the file is somehow scrambled/realigned. The PE-Header is moved 8 bytes back. The sections rdata and pdata appear from nowhere.

What the hack is going on here?

Cheers,
Jan

Comment: Why are you trying to copy `regedit.exe` in the first place? How did you try to move it?

Comment: I wanted to play around with it. For that, I wanted to insert int 3 (0xcc), to simplify debugging (running as normal user and as admin). That's why I wanted to safe it, before editing. I did strg+c strg+v on it in the explorer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not a valid 32-bit file because `C:\Windows\regedit.exe` is a 64-bit executable.  The 32-bit version is `C:\Windows\SysWow64\regedit.exe`.

I can confirm that neither will run if copied out of their default location.

Win7 does some magic under the covers.  If you run regedit from a 32-bit process then you'll get the 32-bit exe from `C:\Windows\SysWow64`.  If you run from a 64-bit process then you get the one in C:\Windows.  So when your 32-bit debugger thinks it's debugging `C:\Windows\regedit.exe` it's actually got `C:\Windows\SysWow64\regedit.exe`.  When you copy regedit.exe out of `C:\Windows` then the redirection doesn't occur and your 32-bit debugger has the 64-bit exe - hence the apparent change.

Comment: Well, I do not think that it is of importance, that olly speaks of a 32-bit file. I can debug the original (C:\windows\regedit.exe), so it ends up, that the file get's somehow changend.

Cheers,
Jan

Comment: I've just added some more info to my answer.

Comment: Any details on _why_ they won't run if copied elsewhere?

Comment: Aaaaah, I see. That solves the scrambling question. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

When copying `regedit.exe`, you have to copy also its `.mui` file located in a `culture` subfolder (e.g. `fr-FR\regedit.exe.mui`), otherwise it won't start.

Answer (score 0):

Several of the tools on NT6 are stupid like this, they will not run without their MUI files (probably in the en-us folder).

I once hacked regedit to run non-elevated as admin and I had to fight it all the way to get that hacked copy to run and I don't remember the exact details of what I had to do...